# How to add "if" statements to user input in schedule program - begginer question

Tags: python

Trying to learn Python from scratch on my own.

I am trying to write an app that pretty much asks me what I want to study one day and then ask me for the time I want to study. That is all fine.

The problem is when I try to add if statements so in case I don't want to study that day, I just input "Rest" and it should print: "This is a rest day", the thing is that I keep getting an error:

CODE SNIPPET:

```
Sunday = input ("What course you want to study on Sunday: ")
    if Sunday = "Rest":
        print ("Sunday is day rest")
    else
        Time_Sunday =  input ("What time would you like to study?: ")
        string = "Sunday: {} by {}"
        output = string.format (Sunday, Time_Sunday)
```

ERROR:

> IndentationError: unexpected indent
> >>> Sunday = input ("What course you want to study on Sunday: ")
> What course you want to study on Sunday:     if Sunday = Rest:
> >>>         print ("Sunday is day rest")
> File "", line 1
> print ("Sunday is day rest")
> ^
> IndentationError: unexpected indent
> >>>     else
> File "", line 1
> else
> ^
> IndentationError: unexpected indent
> >>>         Time_Sunday =  input ("What time would you like to study?: ")
> File "", line 1
> Time_Sunday =  input ("What time would you like to study?: ")
> ^
> IndentationError: unexpected indent
> >>>         string = "Sunday: {} by {}"
> File "", line 1
> string = "Sunday: {} by {}"
> ^
> IndentationError: unexpected indent
> >>>         output = string.format (Sunday, Time_Sunday)
> File "", line 1
> output = string.format (Sunday, Time_Sunday)
> ^
> IndentationError: unexpected indent

I tried many things, but I would like advice to know what I am doing wrong, or at least where to start checking.

Comment: `:` after `else` is missing. Also, there is some unnecessary indentation

Comment: You improperly indented the `if` statement.  Please recheck your tutorial materials before posting here.

Comment: Its seems like you have pasted the code snippet into the interpreter sesion. Since you have an `input` one line of your code gets stored in the `Sunday` variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple mistakes in your code. I think you're trying to do the following:

```
Sunday = input("What course you want to study on Sunday: ")
if Sunday == "Rest":
    print ("Sunday is day rest")
else:
    Time_Sunday = input("What time would you like to study?: ")
    string = "Sunday: {} by {}"
    output = string.format(Sunday, Time_Sunday)
    print(output)
```

1. Your indentation isn't correct, it has to start after the `if` statement
2. You're using `=` to compare, you have to use `==`
3. You have to use `:` after the `else` statement
4. This is not a mistake but I think you want to print `output` so add `print(output)` at the end.

Congratulation for your enthusiasm, happy coding!

Comment: This is it guys, thanks a lot. I believe using Visual Studio Code is meesing with me. I will go back to Python IDLE, not sure why but those simple mistakes were easier to solve with IDLE.

Answer (score 1):

The error is about indentation. You need to have same *levels* of code on the same indent.

Also, an equality is evaluated by `==` not by `=`.

```py
Sunday = input ("What course you want to study on Sunday: ")
if Sunday == "Rest":
    print ("Sunday is day rest")
else:
    Time_Sunday =  input ("What time would you like to study?: ")
    ...
```